# How to upload folders within other folders with batch ftp

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have this batch script right here that uploads my files to FTP. The only problem though is that it does not upload folders that are in other folders. How can I fix that? Below is my code.

```
open ftp.website.com
admin@ftp.website.com
mypassword
cd files
binary
mput C:\Users\Mathew\Desktop\Everything\*
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't, as the default ftp client is very basic. But `ncftp`, for example, can recursively upload directories. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/91149/how-to-ftp-multiple-folders-to-another-server-using-mput-in-unix) for more.

As a side note, this is somewhat off-topic for SO.